# Why do applications appear blurry on Windows when using HiDPI screens?

Tags: windows, scaling

I am taking a course on Digital Image Processing at my college and am wondering why do applications appear blurry on high resolution screens (on Windows). My assumption is that Windows use some kind of scaling algorithm (bilinear/bicubic interpolation) which blurs the edges, but, why not use nearest neighbour or similar algorithm which will keep the text crisp? I couldn't find any technical explanation of this on Google and most of the results are just tutorials on fixing the issue on Windows.

Thanks.

Comment: If you look at how to fix it you might find the reason it's blurry in the first place?

Comment: Nearest-neighbour might be crisp, but will it actually be readable? Be sure to test on non-integer scales (1.25x or 1.5x, not just 2x).

Comment: This is likely due to the scaling options in Windows, and/or your graphics driver. What GPU are you using?

Comment: @spikey_richie The display device is Intel UHD Graphics 620 and render device is NVIDIA GeForce MX150